# Unable to fetch the first entry in SQLlite Database using cursors in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I am trying to fetch all the entries in a database table using SQLite. I ran a query, stored the values in a cursor and then via a loop I fetched all the values. However I can access all the entries except for the first one. Here is my code :

```
mydb1=new Database_CustomTransaction(getApplicationContext());
        Cursor c12 = mydb1.executeQuery("Select * from table1");

        System.out.println(c12);
        if(c12 == null)
        {
             TextView nodataView = new TextView(this);
             nodataView.setId(20);
             nodataView.setText("No Data here !");
             nodataView.setTextSize(20);
        }
        else
        {
            if(flagValue == false)
            {
                c12.moveToFirst();
                flagValue = true;
            }

            while(c12.moveToNext())
            {
                type=c12.getString(0);
                amount = c12.getInt(1);
                spentOn = c12.getString(2);
                date = c12.getString(3);

                listType.add(i,type);
                listSpentOn.add(i,spentOn);
                listAmount.add(i,amount);
                listDate.add(i,date);
                i++;
            }

        }
        latesttrans2.setAdapter(new TestAdapter2(this, listType, listSpentOn,listAmount,listDate));
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c12.moveToFirst();
```

This moves to the first row.

```
while(c12.moveToNext())
```

This moves to the next row *after* the first row.

I would guess that the first call should be just dropped, but only you know what you intended with `flagValue`.

Comment: ' flagValue ' is just a check for the cursor to move to the first column and the first row so that the entries can be retrieved from the beginning.

Comment: `moveToNext()` suffices to move to the first row.

Comment: Yes when u do c12.moveToFirst() after checking the falg value your cursor already points to the first row. Again doing c12.moveToNext() moves it to the next row. Use do while instead of while.

Answer (score 0):

Use do while instead of using just while.I think it is skipping the first entry and straight away moving to next entry.

Comment: I used that. But it is still giving me an error. The error says that index requested with a column 0 and size 0.